# Android ndk not bundle v8 .a file symbols

Tags: android, android-ndk, v8

I have a project which similar too [J2V8](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8/) which bundle v8 to android. But after compile J2V8 has all v8 symbols but [similar project](https://github.com/gengjiawen/V8Android) lose all v8 symbols. You can check the original J2V8.so [here](https://github.com/gengjiawen/V8Android/tree/master/J2V8_lib) by using command

```
nm -D libj2v8.so | grep "GetIsolate"
```

you can get something like

```
003530fc T _ZN2v815SnapshotCreator10GetIsolateEv
003613c4 T _ZN2v86Object10GetIsolateEv
0035f78c T _ZN2v87Context10GetIsolateEv
0038c354 W _ZNK2v88internal10HeapObject10GetIsolateEv
00503a78 T _ZNK2v88internal11MessageImpl10GetIsolateEv
00503b4c T _ZNK2v88internal16EventDetailsImpl10GetIsolateEv
```

But after compile [sample project](https://github.com/gengjiawen/V8Android/tree/master/J2V8_lib), the related output is none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolve this by directly include the v8 source project.

Answer (score 3):

For Android Studio project, either library `.aar` or application `.apk`, during the build process, there is a step stripping the debug symbols of dynamic shared libs, i.e. the `.so`.

If you want to keep all the symbols un-removed, then you can add below configuration into your `build.gradle`.

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip "*/armeabi/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/arm64-v8a/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/armeabi-v7a/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/x86/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/x86_64/*.so"
    } 
    ...
}
```